# How to open/close Spring Integration channel based on environmental variable?

Tags: java, environment-variables, spring-integration

I have a channel that is used as input-channel in a chain.  I need to use it only when the environmental variable sd is not true.  Is it possible to write this condition into the spring-integration file without creating an additional Java filter? So, I would like this chain **not to work** when -Dsd=true in the startup script and work in any other case.

```
<int:channel id="sdCreationChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="sdCreationChannel" output-channel="debugLogger">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="500" />
    <int:filter ref="sdIntegrationExistingRequestSentFilter" method="filter"/>
    <int:transformer ref="sdCreationTransformer" method="transformOrder"/>
    <int:service-activator ref="sdCreationServiceImpl" method="processMessage">
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:service-activator>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<chain>` is a normal `endpoint` which can be started/stopped according it `lifecycle` contract.

So, you can `start/stop` it by its `id` at runtime at any time or with any condition.

Another trick that it is just enough to add `auto-startup="false"` to its definition based on that variable.

M-m-m. I think that should work even with normal property-placeholder:

```
<int:chain auto-startup="${myChain.autoStartup}">
```

From other side you can take a look to the `profile` feature and configure it like this:

```
 <beans profile="myChain.profile">
     <int:chain>
         ....
     </int:chain>
 </beans>
```

**UPDATE**

According to your concern:

> So, I would like this chain not to work when -Dsd=true in the startup script and work in any other case

As I said above: you can just only mark it in `auto-startup="false"` from the beginning, for example using the same `Environment`:

```
<int:chain auto-startup="#{environment.getProperty('sd', true)}">
```

Comment: Can you please look at the question clarification: "So, I would like this chain **not to work** when -Dsd=true in the startup script and work in any other case."