# How to create boolean value from an environmental variable in Spring Integration configuration file?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

Based on [How to open/close Spring Integration channel based on environmental variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539100/how-to-open-close-spring-integration-channel-based-on-environmental-variable) I have the auto-startup condition based on the environmental variable sd:

```
<int:chain auto-startup="#{environment.getProperty('sd', true)}">
```

With the above specification sd can be either true or false otherwise the condition does not work.  What if I want to do startup only if sd equals for example “connect”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `auto-startup` is a `boolean` option on the background anyway, so you have no choice unless return the `boolean` or `true`/`false` string from that SpEL.
BTW, `1`, `0`, `on`, `off` work well, too - `StringToBooleanConverter`.

So, you should just improve your SpEL a bit:

```
<int:chain auto-startup="#{environment.getProperty('sd', 'connect') == 'connect'}">
```